# Aura component not displaying intermittently

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an aura component that displays a top right navigation list of links in the upper right corner of my Community pages.  For the past two years, I have noticed a very intermittent problem that seems to occur during the late night hours or early morning hours in which the navigation bar doesn't appear.  I can even close down the browser & restart it & the navigation bar links still don't show.  However, within a half hour it starts to appear again.  I know this doesn't sound logical.  I can't imagine what is happening that would cause something so intermittent like this.  I am having trouble troubleshooting this because I can't replicate the problem.  It comes and then goes before I can figure out what is going on.  Thoughts?

Comment: I faced a similar problem a while ago, In my case, it was related to knowledge articles. In some of the articles, formatting was such that it messed up the navigation section. Try looking for a similar pattern.

Comment: I too observed some of these illogical intermittent problems. Salesforce keeps pushing patches to various orgs without notice because of which this happens I think. They deliberately disable few configurations during patches.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I will reach out to Salesforce.